# Visual Studio 2010 Professional: class diagram tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I would like to visually design my classes first and then convert them into actual code. I am using VS2010 professional edition. Please recommend me some good online resources for some good hints and practices. I attended a good session in a user group meeting and it was very inspiring to see how easily classes could be visually designed and then converted into code.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a built-in feature. Look at your Solution Explorer,

[image]

or right click your project/class and click View Class Diagram

[image]

Using the class diagram is quite easy..
Just as an example you can right-click your class and add method/field/whatever from there..

[image]

You can find some more info about how to use it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33864ckt.aspx).

There is also the extension for architecture tools.. [here you can find an explanation + a link for download](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/15/visual-studio-2010-how-to-extend-the-architecture-tools-2.aspx)